# Excel - choosing numbers from bigger data set

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, selection, statistics

I have a question about excel (hopefully on the right forum)

I have a data of 100 numbers in excel and I want to randomly choose 30 numbers with the fact that the same number is not chosen again (so by removing the number that was already selected)

And I come across by not knowing on how to do that? I tried with RANDBETWEEN(1;100) and copying it 30 times but it is/can repeat the same number.

Could you please offer me assistance on how to do with worksheet formulas instead of using VBA -that some other forum questions suggest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Excel: Unique random number generator within a range](http://superuser.com/questions/614928/ms-excel-unique-random-number-generator-within-a-range)

Comment: @Raystafarian: I agree that David's proposed dupe doesn't address the question, but neither does the one you proposed; it's missing the critical piece you clarified in your answer.  I can't imagine, though, that this hasn't been asked before.

Comment: @fixer1234 I know it's not my original thought, I've seen it at least once before, so yes - I think the issue is phrasing this question while searching, relevant stuff gets buried.

Comment: Possible duplicates - [Randomise the order of a column of data in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/117933/randomise-the-order-of-a-column-of-data-in-excel) and [Random selection in Excel based on some criteria](http://superuser.com/questions/1028199/random-selection-in-excel-based-on-some-criteria)

Comment: @Raystafarian: LOL.  Figures the perfect dupe would be closed as too broad because "we're not a script writing service".

Comment: @Raystafarian: I voted to reopen your second proposed dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, separate from the VBA as you don't want VBA, use a filter. Put a column next to your range and fill it with `=Rand()`

Drag it down. Then copy and **paste special - values** over top if itself.

Now just sort it ascending or descending and pick either the first 30 or last 30 as your selection.

It's about 99.999% effective unless you have millions in your list.

[image]